# Using git-p4 to setup a git clone of a perforce client

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I have a perforce client which maps several perforce paths into my local client.
These perforce paths are for libraries and the main code line.

How do I use git-p4 to setup a clone of the entire client in a separate directory?

From what I see git-p4 can only clone specific depot paths. I would like to clone
an entire client: suppose my perforce client is test_client. I would like to do:

```
cd git_area
cp ../perforce/test_client/.perforce .
git-p4 clone
```

or something similar which will pull in all the directories into this separate git directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most git-p4 operations work on a single Perforce depot path.  (I could be wrong on that, I haven't used it often.)

Does your workspace follow a pattern where you have one code line you really work on, and the rest of the files are libraries that you don't modify?  In other words is your workspace view something like:

```
//depot/my_proj/src/... //ws/src/...
//depot/libs/libA/... //ws/libs/libA/...
```

If so, you could probably use git-p4 on the source code, and continue to get the read-only dependencies from your Perforce workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use a branch-spec in perforce to combine your perforce paths into a single location.

That would only work if you're happy with just getting the tip, without history.

AFAIK, git-p4 uses p4 print, so it doesn't care about the local mapping.