# git-p4 submission failure

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I am using git-p4 to work with git locally and trying to submit my changes back to the
perforce server. Its the submitting changes back to the server that I am failing to do.

I have a client set up so that it includes all the library dependencies in the client
(following recommendations in [Using git-p4 to setup a git clone of a perforce client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694250/using-git-p4-to-setup-a-git-clone-of-a-perforce-client))

```
//depot/libA/... //workspace/libA/...
//depot/libB/... //workspace/libB/...
```

However for the main line source, I am doing the following in the workspace directory:

```
git-p4 clone //depot/my_project
```

This creates and populates my_project directory in workspace.

So that the code in src can refer to the libraries.

Problem is that when I do git-p4 rebase I get the following error:

```
$git-p4 rebase
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2362, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2357, in main
    if not cmd.run(args):
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2051, in run
    sync.run([])
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2004, in run
    changes = self.p4.p4ChangesForPaths(self.depotPaths, self.changeRange)
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 232, in p4ChangesForPaths
    assert depotPaths
AssertionError
```

When I do git-p4 submit (after i make single change and do a git commit -a -m "test"):

```
$ git-p4 submit --verbose
Reading pipe: git name-rev HEAD
Reading pipe: git config git-p4.allowSubmit
Reading pipe: git rev-parse --symbolic  --remotes
Reading pipe: git rev-parse p4/master
Reading pipe: git notes --ref=git-p4 show 6b75260b956cb72102014783fcfcb2e0da6eb637
Reading pipe: git notes --ref=git-p4 show HEAD~0
Reading pipe: git notes --ref=git-p4 show HEAD~1
Reading pipe: git notes --ref=git-p4 show HEAD~2
Reading pipe: git notes --ref=git-p4 show HEAD~3
```

.....

It takes forever (is it asking the server for ALL changeset??) and fails with error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2362, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2357, in main
    if not cmd.run(args):
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 1088, in run
    self.depotPath = settings['depot-paths'][0]
KeyError: 'depot-paths'
```

I should note that I have not used git config to set up any of the git-p4 options
(the wiki at https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git-p4_Usage does not seem to mention
that it is needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does you client-spec include `//depot/my_project/...` ?

Maybe you can have your libraries in one client-spec, and your project in another.

Maybe:

```
working/
    project-git/
       .perforce -> P4CONFIG with project-spec
       <p4-git project checkout>
    .perforce -> P4CONFIG with libs-spec
    libraries
perforce/
    .perforce -> P4CONFIG with project-spec
    <p4 project checkout>
```

Comment: No - it does not and that was the problem. Thanks! Is it possible to have depot paths in the client spec and not sync when I do a p4 sync ... ? Because when I do the sync, perforce could overwrite the git repository.

Comment: I have a similar problem, except that my client-spec includes the //depot/address. Does anyone know a different solution?

Comment: @WojciechGórski If you have a similar but different problem, please ask it as a question, referring to this one, and *highlighting* the differences.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I posted an answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367328/git-p4-depot-path-error/12384217#12384217