# git p4 depot-path error

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I have a problem setting up git with perforce using git-p4.
After finishing all the steps from this excellent blog post: http://owenou.com/2011/03/23/git-up-perforce-with-git-p4.html, I try to add a new file/modify an existing file in the local git repository.

When trying to rebase I get:

```
$git-p4 rebase  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2362, in <module>  
    main()  
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2357, in main  
    if not cmd.run(args):  
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2051, in run  
    sync.run([])  
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 2004, in run  
    changes = self.p4.p4ChangesForPaths(self.depotPaths, self.changeRange)  
  File "/home/user/bin/git-p4", line 232, in p4ChangesForPaths  
    assert depotPaths  
AssertionError
```

After committing the change to git and executing
`git p4 submit --verbose`
which should push the changes to the p4 repository, I get 65534 lines of output:

```
Reading pipe: git notes --ref=git-p4 show HEAD~1  
Reading pipe: git notes --ref=git-p4 show HEAD~2  
[...]  
Reading pipe: git notes --ref=git-p4 show HEAD~65534  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/home/wgorski/opt/git-p4/git-p4", line 2754, in <module>  
    main()  
  File "/home/wgorski/opt/git-p4/git-p4", line 2749, in main  
    if not cmd.run(args):  
  File "/home/wgorski/opt/git-p4/git-p4", line 1125, in run  
    self.depotPath = settings['depot-paths'][0]  
KeyError: 'depot-paths'
```

Needless to say, the changes are not pushed to the p4 repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the git version. I had git 1.7.0 installed and the git-p4 script requires git version >= 1.7.1.
I suggest updating to the latest git version.

If upgrading git is not an option, you could downgrade the git-p4 script to a revision which doesn't use notes, like this:

`git checkout 994ec6ce71cb03786a27a77da77ac33a9e53e090 .`

after downgrading git-p4, you need to check out the local git repo from perforce.